# Alternatives to pulling data from ATOM Data Feed

Tags: excel, ms-access, reporting-services, powerpivot, atom-feed

I did some extensive searching and was unable to find the answer to my question:

Are there alternatives to pulling data using ATOM Data Feeds other than Microsoft Powerpivot? I am trying to set up a connection to MS Access so I can populate some tables using data that currently has to be accessed through an SSRS embedded on a Sharepoint dashboard. I do not have access to the server, so I can't create my own connection at this time. Powerpivot has been the only method that returns data outside of manually going to the Sharepoint. I want the data to automatically populate in MS Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the Power Query Add-In - it can connect to SharePoint Lists or OData feeds:

SharePoint:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/connect-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA104019822.aspx

OData:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/connect-to-an-odata-feed-HA104019824.aspx

Comment: The problem is that SSRS provides [Atom complient data feeds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181243(SQL.110).aspx), but Power Query cannot [import](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f9bfec2-2363-45f2-8931-db769a5c2309/issue-consuming-odata-feed-with-power-query-not-in-power-bi?forum=powerquery) them.